# ¿Cómo colocar JavaScript en una clase HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo que hacer un proyecto en `JavaScript` para una asignatura y quería usar un diseño `HTML` decente para que no solo se muestre el `js` cuando se ejecute.

[image: Parte superior]

[image: Parte inferior]

Esto es como se ve la pagina, el `js` se inserta en la parte inferior (ese cuadrado oscuro) y no consigo cambiarlo. ¿Puedo darle al `js` un estilo `CSS`? ¿Como puedo colocarlo en la clase "col-sm"?
Sinceramente no tengo mucha idea de como se programa en estos lenguajes y estoy un poco a prueba-error.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Graficos por Computador</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <section class="probootstrap-cover">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row probootstrap-vh-100 align-items-center text-center">
          <div class="col-sm">

              <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
                      <!-- uncomment lines below to include extra p5 libraries -->
                      <script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
                      <!--<script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>-->
                <script src="js/Prueba1.js"></script>
                <!-- this line removes any default padding and style. you might only need one of these values set. -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

El `JavaScript` es simplemente un `Canvas` que marca los pixeles donde haces `click`:

```
function setup(){

    createCanvas(800,500);
    background(225);


}

function mouseClicked(){
    //arc(mouseX,mouseY,40,0,2* Math.PI);
    point (mouseX,mouseY)

    //rectangulo

}
```

EDIT:
He creado un `Canvas`usando el comando de `HTML`, pero de esta forma no se como integrar las funciones como `MouseClicked()` que se como programar en `JavaScript`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500" style="border:2px solid#000000;"> </canvas>
```

Comment: En si cual es tu objetivo ? dar estilos ? o cual ? cuando dices `js un estilo CSS` es darle un estilo al div que lo contiene ?

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO Hola, lo que intento es colocar el `canvas` de el JavaScript en el div `col-sm`
He conseguido crear un canvas dentro del div usando `<canvas id"canvas"></canvas>`en HTML, pero lo que necesito es que el canvas generado en el JS se coloque en el centro